# iframe in a full url?

Tags: html, iframe

I need to use an iframe to pull in a page from another site but i dont know how to show a page from siteb.com on sitea.com

any ideas

Answer (score 5):

Just set the source of the iframe to the site from the other domain. For example, if this was on a page from sitea:

```
<iframe src="http://siteb.com/some/path/page.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the page from the other site onto your server. Then, display the page you downloaded on your server.